# One user can't run program while others can

Tags: windows-7, autocad

I am having an issue a little bit strange. I installed AutoCAD LT 2015 in some computers in my network with administrator account, and I'm having issues with one user in particular. When he starts AutoCAD, nothing happen, although if I run as administrator it works like a charm.

I did the next tests:

- Uninstalled and reinstall AutoCAD.
- Gave user admin rights to the program.
- Login with other users (same permissions as this one) and they are able to run it.
- Check the user account on the active directory and it's exactly the same as the others.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the problematic user logs into other computers can he run AutoCAD there?

Comment: Yes he can. It related to his account and to that computer particularly.

Answer (score 0):

Install SysInternals **Process Monitor** from Microsoft and use it to monitor Autocad launching and failing for that account. Chances are it's a permissions problem on some file or registry entry (since it works when run as Administrator).

Once you know what is hanging the program, you can tweak permissions to correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that, but for now i managed to save the admin credentials when he runs AutoCad from his computer. So now he runs it as administrator, but he doesn't know. Not a fix but a workaround. Thank you.